# How to select entity properties based on a condition?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have this `select`:

```
 var CP = db.ContasPagar.Include(c => c.ContasPagarP).Where(c => c.Quitado == true && c.Caixa == false && c.BancoId == id).Select(c => new BancoList
        {
            Id = c.Id,
            Data = c.DataPagamento,
            Valor = c.Total,
            Tipo = "D",
            Documento = "Fat. Contas Diversas " + c.ContasPagarP.Codigo,

        }).ToList();
        var FP = db.FaturaContasPagar.Include(c => c.FaturaContasPagarP).Where(c => c.Quitado == true && c.Caixa == false && c.BancoId == id).Select(c => new BancoList
        {
            Id = c.Id,
            Data = c.DataPagamento,
            Valor = c.Total,
            Tipo = "D",
            Documento = "Fat. Nota Fiscal: " + c.FaturaContasPagarP.NotaFiscal,
        }).ToList();
        var CR = db.ContasReceber.Include(c => c.ContasReceberP).Where(c => c.Quitado == true && c.Caixa == false && c.BancoId == id).Select(c => new BancoList
        {
            Id = c.Id,
            Data = c.DataPagamento,
            Valor = c.Total,
            Tipo = "C",
            Documento = "Fat. Contas Diversas " + c.ContasReceberP.Codigo,
        }).ToList();
        var FR = db.FaturaContasReceber.Include(c => c.FaturaContasReceberP).Where(c => c.Quitado == true && c.Caixa == false && c.BancoId == id).Select(c => new BancoList
        {
            Id = c.Id,
            Data = c.DataPagamento,
            Valor = c.Total,
            Tipo = "C",
            Documento = c.FaturaContasReceberP.NotaFiscal != null ? "Fat. NFSe: " + c.FaturaContasReceberP.NotaFiscal : null + c.FaturaContasReceberP.NotaFiscalProdutos != null ? " NFe: " + c.FaturaContasReceberP.NotaFiscalProdutos : null,
        }).ToList();
        var BC = db.BancoMovimento.Where(c => c.Credito == true && c.ContaId == id).Select(c => new BancoList
        {
            Id = c.Id,
            Data = c.DataMovimento,
            Valor = c.Valor,
            Tipo = "C",
            Documento = c.Historico
        }).ToList();
        var BD = db.BancoMovimento.Where(c => c.Credito == false && c.ContaId == id).Select(c => new BancoList
        {
            Id = c.Id,
            Data = c.DataMovimento,
            Valor = c.Valor,
            Tipo = "D",
            Documento = c.Historico
        }).ToList();

        var union = CP.Union(FP).Union(FR).Union(CR).Union(BC).Union(BD).OrderBy(c => c.Data).ToList();
```

Only a problem occurs, not always the `Nfse` is filled, and not always the `NotaFiscalProdutos` is filled, I need it to check for these values, to add into the `Documento`.

If only the `NumeroNfse` field has value, would look like this: `Fat. NFSe: " + c.FaturaContasReceberP.NFSe.NumeroNfse`  and if only `NotaFiscalProdutos` retorar `" NFe: " + c.FaturaContasReceberP.NotaFiscalProdutos`, and if both have return the two.

**EDIT**

```
Documento = (c.FaturaContasReceberP.NotaFiscal != null ? "Fat. NFSe: " + c.FaturaContasReceberP.NotaFiscal : null + c.FaturaContasReceberP.NotaFiscalProdutos != null ? " NFe: " + c.FaturaContasReceberP.NotaFiscalProdutos : null).Trim()
```

I changed to this form, but also does not work as expected.

Comment: Share us your current code for `FR`, and the existing records in the database, the current result for `FR`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be a long statement if you put it in the `Select` and would affect the readability of your code significantly. Here's one way to get around this...

In your entity that belongs to `FaturaContasReceber`, create a read-only property that looks like this:

```
public string Documento
{
    get
    {
        string nfse = FaturaContasReceberP?.NFSe?.NumeroNfse;
        string nfe = FaturaContasReceberP?.NotaFiscalProdutos;
        string documento = (nfse ? $"Fat. NFSe: {nfse}" : "") +
                           (nfe ? $" NFe: {nfe}" : "");
        return documento.Trim();
    }
}
```

Then you can easily use it like this:

```
var FR = db.FaturaContasReceber
                .Include(c => c.FaturaContasReceberP)
                .Where(c => c.Quitado && !c.Caixa && c.BancoId == id)
                .ToList()
                .Select(c => new BancoList
                {
                    Id = c.Id,
                    Data = c.DataPagamento,
                    Valor = c.Total,
                    Tipo = "C",
                    Documento = c.Documento
                }).ToList();
```

### Edit:

If you insist on doing it in the `Select`, you can do it like this:

```
Documento = (c.FaturaContasReceberP?.NFSe?.NumeroNfse ? "Fat. NFSe: " + c.FaturaContasReceberP.NFSe.NumeroNfse : "" +
             c.FaturaContasReceberP?.NotaFiscalProdutos ? " NFe: " + c.FaturaContasReceberP.NotaFiscalProdutos : "").Trim()
```

But I would advise you to use the first solution.

Comment: In the case the document is in the table I'm BancoList filling, but he's returning multiple errors when I try to get around in this form.Remembering that I use this to make a Union between BancoList selects. So in this way will not solve the problem, because this rule is only for this select.

Comment: @marianac_costa I'm not sure I understand; can you please elaborate? But first, try the updated code; I've fixed some typos.

Comment: Still does not work as expected. I can't change the property because I fill it with another table, and their Union.

Comment: The treatment needs to be right here `Documento = c.Documento`

Comment: @marianac_costa You don't need to change any existing properties; you'll just _add_ a new read-only property as I've shown above. I've chosen to name it `Documento` but you can name it anything you like. Then you can use `Document = c.YourPropertyName`. What exactly is not working for you?

Comment: This property is already to read-only, and in other camps to step it to make the Union between the tables, I will update the question to better understand

Comment: @marianac_costa The `Union` part is irrelevant here. The read-only property that I proposed only works as a "helper function" to make your `Select` easy to read and follow. Anyway, I've added another solution that doesn't require the additional property. Choose whichever you prefer.

Comment: `Documento = "Fat." + (
    (c.FaturaContasReceberP.NotaFiscal != null ? "NFSe: " + c.FaturaContasReceberP.NotaFiscal : "") +
    (c.FaturaContasReceberP.NotaFiscalProdutos != null ? " NFe: " + c.FaturaContasReceberP.NotaFiscalProdutos : "")
).Trim()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [?:operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)

```
    Tipo = "C",
Documento = c.FaturaContasReceberP.NFSe != null ? "Fat. NFSe: " + c.FaturaContasReceberP.NFSe.NumeroNfse:null + c.FaturaContasReceberP.NotaFiscalProdutos!=null? " NFe: " + c.FaturaContasReceberP.NotaFiscalProdutos:null,
```

Comment: How does not work, only appears the `NFSe`, even if he is null